# NullPointerException in Fragments onAttach for findViewById

Tags: android

So I have a curious problem I'm not able to solve right now.

RoomGamesFragment

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    roomActivity = (RoomActivity) activity;

    gameTabContainerView = (LinearLayout) roomActivity.findViewById(R.id.game_tab_container); // findViewById returns null

    // NullPointerException
    gameTabContainerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        }
    });
}
```

This works totally fine when opening the activity which contains the fragment. But here is the problem: If I leave the activity open, put the app in the background (by clicking the home button), use other apps and then open my app again after some time, I get the NullPointerException, because `findViewById` returns null now.
How can I prevent this? Is the Activity removed from the stack, which leads to the Exception? I know I could just check for `null`, but I need the `onClickListener`, even when I return to the app after it has been in the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not perform this code in `onAttach()` but rather in `onActivityCreated()`. This is because the "View" is not yet created. `onAttach()` is above the `onCreateView()` in the Fragment lifecycle.

For more info : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating